# Reconstruir un arbol a partir de su inorden y preorden

Tags: python, teoría-de-grafos

```
Preorden = ["h","a","b","f","g","c","m","n","d"]
Inorden = ["f","b","g","a","c","h","n","m","d"]

def PreordenReconstruccion(P,I):
 Izquierda=[]
 Derecha=[]
 x=0
 Raiz=P[0]
 while I[x] != Raiz:
    Izquierda.append(I[x])
    x=x+1
 Derecha=I[x+1:len(I)]
 print Izquierda
 print Derecha
PreordenReconstruccion(Preorden,Inorden)
```

tengo que reconstruir un arbol con su inorden y preorden al usar esa funcion 
cojo la raiz que es h y divido lo que queda en el lado izquierdo del arbol, asi quedandome

H

F,B,G,A,C     -     N,M,D

en la lista inorden 
en la lista de preorden me quedaria
**a**,b,f,g    -   **m**,n,d
de los cuales deberia tomar a y m que son mis nuevas raices y repetir el porceso anterior de separarlos de izquierda y derecha. hasta reconstruir el arbol, como puedo continuar con mi codigo soy conciente que debe ser recursivo pero no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se si los arreglos estan bien ordenados, por lo tanto voy a explicarte mi solucion usando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso los recorridos son los siguientes:

1. Secuencia de recorrido de preorden: F, B, A, D, C, E, G, I, H (raíz, izquierda, derecha)
2. Secuencia de recorrido de inorden: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I (izquierda, raíz, derecha); note cómo esto produce una secuencia ordenada

Tu codigo esta bien, el problema es que si quieres elegir siempre la raiz el elemento `P[0]`, tienes que modificar este arreglo en cada llamada recursiva, en mi caso despues de la primera ejecucion tenemos los siguientes arreglos:

```py
P = [F, B, A, D, C, E, G, I, H]
I = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]

Raiz = F
Izquierda = [A, B, C, D, E]
Derecha = [G, H, I]

# Entonces las llamadas serian:

PreordenReconstruccion ([B,A,D,C,E], [A, B, C, D, E])
PreordenReconstruccion ([G,I,H], [G, H, I])
```

Por lo tanto en la siguiente llamada recursiva, `P` debe tomar los valores que hay entre B (para ignorar el F) hasta E, asi nos aseguramos que el `P[0]` sea la raiz en cada llamada recursiva. En la segunda llamada `P` debe tomar los valores desde G hasta H. Adjunto el codigo para que quede mas claro y la salida que obtuve:

```py
Preorden = ["F", "B", "A", "D", "C", "E", "G", "I", "H"]
Inorden = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]

def PreordenReconstruccion(P,I):
    if (len(I) == 0 or len(P) == 0):
        return
    else:
        Izquierda=[]
        Derecha=[]
        x=0
        Raiz=P[0]
        while I[x] != Raiz:
            Izquierda.append(I[x])
            x=x+1
        Derecha=I[x+1:len(I)]
        print (Izquierda , "<-", Raiz, "->", Derecha)

        PreordenReconstruccion(P[1:len(Izquierda)+1],Izquierda)
        PreordenReconstruccion(P[len(P)-len(Derecha):len(P)],Derecha)

PreordenReconstruccion(Preorden,Inorden)
```

Esta fue la salida que obtuve:

```py
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] <- F -> ['G', 'H', 'I']
['A'] <- B -> ['C', 'D', 'E']
[] <- A -> []
['C'] <- D -> ['E']
[] <- C -> []
[] <- E -> []
[] <- G -> ['H', 'I']
['H'] <- I -> []
[] <- H -> []
```

Y con tus datos:

```py
['f', 'b', 'g', 'a', 'c'] <- h -> ['n', 'm', 'd']
['f', 'b', 'g'] <- a -> ['c']
['f'] <- b -> ['g']
[] <- f -> []
[] <- g -> []
[] <- c -> []
['n'] <- m -> ['d']
[] <- n -> []
[] <- d -> []
```

Espero haberte ayudado!